# intuit customer account data PHP authorization 401 error

Tags: api, intuit-partner-platform

Trying to use the intuit customer account data for PHP, and I keep getting an error that it cannot authorize (401)

I followed the example here:
https://github.com/pleslie/phpaggcat/

but it is spitting out:
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [errorInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [errorType] => APP_ERROR [errorCode] => authentication.user.credentials [errorMessage] => internal api error while processing request [correlationId] => gw-3b201d78-c8e8-40fb-bc06-e24414813ec9 ) ) Institution Name (1):

Does anyone possibly know why? It seems to be doing the same exact error while using their API explorer as well-

Any help is appreciated.